# What are the best tools to make an online card game?

Tags: javascript, sockets, browser, frameworks

I'm looking for some event/reactive online tools to make a card game in a browser.
I think JS is most appropriate here but I'm open to all propositions.

I already tried VueJS / Node with Socket.IO but I think it's very messy and not organized enough to make a project like this. So I was wondering if you guys knew some frameworks to make the job.

The projects is to make an online card game like poker.

Thanks !

Comment: If you want to make a game that is playable in a browser. You could try Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we really do some lightweighted online card game with Unity ? I'm afraid that it requires too much resources and slow down the game :/

Comment: You can play some unity based games on itch.io to see the performance.

Comment: Apparently, I need the Unity Web Player to play this kind of games and it's not available on Google Chrome... Which is important because Chrome is the most popular browser...

Comment: Unity doesn't require the web player addon anymore since it compiles to HTML5 and JavaScript

Comment: Oh, ok thanks, I didn't know that. Well, I will simply check every things Unity can offer to me ! Thanks for your time !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217793/discussion-between-antoine-joublin-and-john).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [pixi.js](https://www.pixijs.com/) or [phaser 3+](https://phaser.io/).
Also I've wright one of my card-games only using html+css+javascript.
For back-end you could use whatever you want. NodeJS + websockets is good choice!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've also managed to create a game with only html/js but the most difficult part is the online and the only solution I found so far is Socket.IO. Do you have something else to handle the online part of the game ?

Comment: I just used common [websocket lib](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) for front-end and [ws lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#protocol-support) for back-end.
But socket.IO is good solution too.

Answer (score 2):

If the main matter is the realtime database connection (for which you are looking for websockets), you could create the game and store it's data to `firebase firestore`, this way you could get everything synced in real time with a less pain than a node server setup, (for this purpose), if you need some backend functionality you could also work with `firebase functions` in order to achieve some backend stuff, also you could even store your project on `firebase hosting`, have an authentication ready platform with `firebase auth` and depending on your needs you would not even pay a penny (this really depends on the usage)

Hope this could at least be an option to consider.

Check the firebase documentation: [FIREBASE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Even if you wish to work with `Unity` instead of `VueJS` you can also use firebase for all this matters.